# javascript: HTML5 Audio Player

Tags: javascript

HTML5 Audio Player is not working on my mobile theme, but it works well on my desktop theme

**javascript** of my html5 player:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#JQAudioPlayer1").fdAudioPlayer({sourceURL:"/player_files/test6.xml",swfURL:"http://example.de/player_files/jplayer.swf",solution:"html,flash",mouseWheelEnabled:true,trackAutostart:false,trackRandom:true,trackRepeat:true,trackVolume:70,trackTitleScrollEnabled:true,trackTitleScrollDuration:5000,trackTitleScrollDelay:3000,trackTitleFormat:"_ALBUM_ - _TRACK_",timeShowHour:false,seekBarTipEnabled:true,playlistState:"expanded",playlistAnimationEasing:"easeOutQuad",playlistAnimationDuration:200,playlistButtonEnabled:true,playlistButtonString:"PLAYLIST",playlistVisibleRowCount:7,playlistAutoResize:false,thumbnailsScrollingStep:1,thumbnailsScrollingDuration:500,thumbnailsScrollingEasing:"easeOutQuad",thumbTipEnabled:false});
    });
```

**html** code of the player on desktop theme:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#JQAudioPlayer1").fdAudioPlayer({sourceURL:"/wp-content/themes/audio/test6.xml",swfURL:"/player_files/jplayer.swf",solution:"html,flash",mouseWheelEnabled:true,trackAutostart:false,trackRandom:true,trackRepeat:true,trackVolume:70,trackTitleScrollEnabled:true,trackTitleScrollDuration:5000,trackTitleScrollDelay:3000,trackTitleFormat:"_ALBUM_ - _TRACK_",timeShowHour:false,seekBarTipEnabled:true,playlistState:"expanded",playlistAnimationEasing:"easeOutQuad",playlistAnimationDuration:200,playlistButtonEnabled:true,playlistButtonString:"PLAYLIST",playlistVisibleRowCount:7,playlistAutoResize:false,thumbnailsScrollingStep:1,thumbnailsScrollingDuration:500,thumbnailsScrollingEasing:"easeOutQuad",thumbTipEnabled:false});
    });
```

**html** code of the player on mobile theme:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#JQAudioPlayer1").fdAudioPlayer({sourceURL:"http://www.example.de/wp-content/themes/audio/test6.xml",swfURL:"/player_files/jplayer.swf",solution:"html,flash",mouseWheelEnabled:true,trackAutostart:false,trackRandom:true,trackRepeat:true,trackVolume:70,trackTitleScrollEnabled:true,trackTitleScrollDuration:5000,trackTitleScrollDelay:3000,trackTitleFormat:"_ALBUM_ - _TRACK_",timeShowHour:false,seekBarTipEnabled:true,playlistState:"expanded",playlistAnimationEasing:"easeOutQuad",playlistAnimationDuration:200,playlistButtonEnabled:true,playlistButtonString:"PLAYLIST",playlistVisibleRowCount:7,playlistAutoResize:false,thumbnailsScrollingStep:1,thumbnailsScrollingDuration:500,thumbnailsScrollingEasing:"easeOutQuad",thumbTipEnabled:false});
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have noted `sourceURL` changes in each case.

This is why your player fails. He certainly cannot find files.

You should find where the `sourceURL` path is generated, and ensure it is the same for all.

Look:

**/player_files/test6.xml ≠ /wp-content/themes/audio/test6.xml**

```
{sourceURL:"**/player_files/test6.xml**",swfURL:"**http://example.de/player_files/jplayer.swf**",

    {sourceURL:"**/wp-content/themes/audio/test6.xml**",swfURL:"**/player_files/jplayer.swf**",solution:"html,flash",

    {sourceURL:"http://www.example.de/wp-content/themes/audio/test6.xml",swfURL:"/player_files/jplayer.swf",;
```

Comment: the sourceurl pathe of my xml file ist /wp-content/themes/audio/test6.xml

Comment: and it works well on my desktop theme, but not on the mobile theme

Comment: I d bet the problem stands in `http://www.example.de/wp-content`, what do you get in typing `http://www.example.de/wp-content/themes/audio/test6.xml`in your desktop browser ?

Comment: Modify your mobile theme to have the same sourceUrl as desktop one.